# What is the default character encoding for HTML?

Tags: html, character-encoding

For some reason, the plain text character `–` on the html side is being dsiplayed as `â€“`.  The only thing I can think that would be attributed to this is the character encoding.  My guess is that it's utf-8, but not sure how I am getting the weird characters.  **Is there an explanation?**

What I mean by default is if the `charset` isn't specified.

Comment: Is the charset being specified? Typically I add a meta tag specifying the charset as utf-8 in the head of the html document. The doctype is for the browser to know what mode to run in (matters to older versions of IE).

Comment: The default is Unicode: http://www.w3.org/QA/2008/03/html-charset.html (3rd paragraph)

Comment: @kinakuta charset is what I meant, thanks for pointing out. But nothing is being specified for it.

Comment: @alfasin it says no such thing about a default, and while all character entities are interpreted in terms of Unicode, there isn't even a single Unicode encoding to be a default (UTF-8 or UTF-16?). There's also the problem of a web full of legacy code to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `!DOCTYPE` doesn't set a character encoding, the `meta` element together with the (newly standardized) `charset` attribute does. If it's absent I'm not entirely sure how the browser determines the encoding.

I believe the problem you're having though is that your page is saved in one encoding and served in another.

Just make sure you set `<meta charset="utf8"/>` and make sure your document is in fact utf8 and it should work.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` did it for me.  I would still be curious as to what it would be for IE 8.

Comment: If you use HTML5 (the `<!DOCTYPE html>`-doctype) `<meta charset="utf8"/>` is valid. And regardless I think it should work.

Comment: Don't worry about IE8, it will grok the `http-equiv` form. I'm pretty sure IE4 would, but I'm not too sure about earlier than that. If you can, set the HTTP headers from the server to match also.

Comment: It should be `<meta charset="utf-8">`. `utf8` (without hyphen) is not listed in the [Character sets standard](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xml), referred to by the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.charset)

Answer (score 10):

That certainly looks like UTF-8 being interpreted as something else.

HTML doesn't have a default. It's picked up from the headers of the transfer protocol (normally HTTP) or failing that, from a BOM, from `meta` elements or, in the case of XHTML, the XML declaration. In the absence of any of those, the user-agent guesses.

HTTP has a default of ISO-8859-1, which even one HTML spec described as having "proved useless" [[source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#spec-char-encoding)] (they don't even go into the fact that a large amount of stuff out there labelled as ISO-8859-1 is actually CP-1252).

Hence. Forget about defaults, always set your HTTP headers **and** your meta elements (in case it's saved as a file).

And always do so as UTF-8. Anything else in this day and age is just an act of masochism.

Comment: I experienced `Android`, `Windows`, and `iOS` API; they all did assume UTF-8, for `JSON` responses at least (if `charset` was missing from `Content-Type` header).

Answer (score -3):

i use the default that Eclipse for PHP provides with, and face no problems:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
```

Comment: I would definitely _not_ recommend using ISO. UTF8 is far superior.

Comment: Try that one with `<p>My favourite animé series is シリアルエクスペリメンツ・レイン</p>`. Or even with `<p>Why not just use the English name “Serial Experiments Lain”</p>`. Legacy character sets are always more trouble in the long run.